# How to render function from string in vue directive?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, rich-text-editor, tiptap

I'm trying to take a function from an object array and run it in a `@click` event on a `DOM element`. The only way I found to do this was by saving the function as a `string` inside the object, and render it with `new Function`:

```
const func = 'editor.chain().focus().toggleBold().run()'

const renderFunction = new Function('return ' + '(func) => { return func }')()

console.log(renderFunction(func))
```

Output:

```
editor.chain().focus().toggleBold().run()
```

This seems to return `func` correctly inside the `script setup` tags, which is the function I want to run inside the `@click` directive but it doesn't seem to work inside the directive. When I click on this icon:

```
<fa class="icon" 
v-for="(button, key) in tool.buttons" 
:key="key" 
type="button" 
:icon="[ 'fas', button.icon ]" 
:title="button.text" 
@click="renderFunction('editor.chain().focus().toggleBold().run()')"
></fa>
```

Nothing happens and no error is shown. This function should actually set the font inside `tiptap` rich text editor to `bold`. Adding `console.log` to `renderFunction`:

```
const renderFunction = new Function('return ' + '(func) => { return console.log(func) }')()
```

returns `func` as a string upon click so at least the string value seems to be sent to the function correctly, but why is the function not run inside the directive?

Comment: You're still passing a string to your new function, so nothing is different. You could do `const realFunctionFromString = new Function(\`return ${func}\`);`.

Comment: I've tried ```const renderFunction = (func) => { new Function(`return ${ func }`)() }``` since it showed `func is not defined` but now when I try to run `@click="renderFunction('editor.chain().focus().toggleBold().run()')"` it shows `editor is not defined.`. When I run `editor.chain...` as a function in the directive, it works.

Comment: Yikes. Not sure what's going on here; I'm no Vue expert. By the way, there's a problem in your `renderFunction()` code: you're not returning the value of function, so... change it to `const renderFunction = func => new Function("return " + func)();`.

Comment: This is XY problem that should be solved in a different way. Eval is evil. new Function isn't used in normal situations. Consider addressing the real case instead, how is `editor` defined and why does editor.chain().focus().toggleBold().run() need to be an expression?

Comment: @EstusFlask it's how `tiptap` handles its editor toolbar button functions. I find it limiting too.

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov Can you provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for you case? I'm sure it can be solved in a conventional way, but there needs to be enough information for that. As for you question with new Function, these functions have different context of execution. `editor` variable is likely available in script setup block, but in template there are only instance properties that are masked with Vue template syntax that allows to omit `this`, so it would be `this.editor`